Posix Message Queue: Message (of type Struct) is always too long
I am starting to learn using Posix Message Queues in C. (my host is Kubuntu 22.04)
I am Trying to write a program, that starts a provided number of threads that are waiting for messages (Message = struct that contains a Pointer to an allocated Memory) in the Queue. If there is a message, the fastest Thread takes the Message and process it somehow.
The main Program just starts the Threads, fills up the message queue and then waits till every thread finished, to display the results . But i always got the "Message too long"-error.
On my research I found out that this should be in general possible. But as i didn't get a working program for days, I started breaking it down and I got the following code that is still not working because of the "Message too long"-error.
As I understand:

for the message Queue there can be a maximum message size set (I chose the size of my struct: sizeof(message_t) ).
For sending i am just using my own struct and the sizeof my struct.
when reading a message I must tell the mq_receive the size of the message to read (which I also set to sizeof(message_t)

sending always works, and when I just sent one message to the queue, the content if the file (/dev/mqueue/test-123) showed me the correct QSIZE: 70 (20 + 50)
Am I missing something on here? Or am I just wrong that it is possible to put a struct into the message queue.
Additionally: As the only Communication through the Message Queue happens between parent process and threads, in my mind it should be safe to share addresses between them.
The reduced code looks like this:
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct message {
    //long int message_type; 
    char path[50];
    char name[20];
} message_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* queue_name = "/test-123";

    // Message Queue File Descriptor for Sending
    mqd_t msgq_fd ;

    // Attributes of the Message queue
    struct mq_attr attr = { 0 };
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 100;
    attr.mq_msgsize = sizeof(message_t);

    // (Create and) open the message Queue for Writing only
    if((msgq_fd = mq_open(queue_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0660, &attr)) == -1) {
        perror("Sender: mq_open failed");
        exit(4);
    }

    //Put 5 Messages into the Message queue
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       message_t *msg = calloc(1,sizeof(message_t));
       strcpy(msg->name,"test");
       strcpy(msg->path,"testpath");

        printf("Message %d prepared...", i);

        // Error Sending 
        if(mq_send(msgq_fd, (const char *)msg, sizeof(message_t), 0) == -1) {
                perror("Sender: unable to send message");
                mq_close(msgq_fd);
                exit(10);
        }
        printf("queued\n");
        sleep(1);

    }

    printf("\nReading messages from Queue\n");
    int ret = 0;

    // Struct for storing the message from the Message Queue
    message_t recv_msg;

    // Read 5 messages from the Message Queue
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Message %d:\n",i+1);
        sleep(1);

        ret = mq_receive(msgq_fd,(char*)&recv_msg,sizeof(attr.mq_msgsize),NULL);

        // Error receiving
        if(ret == -1) {
            //printf("%d, %p, %ld\n",msgq_fd2, &recv_msg, sizeof(message_t));
            perror("Message receive error");
        }

        // Print the content of the received message
        printf("%s/%s\n\n",recv_msg.path,recv_msg.name);
    }
    return 0;
}


The message size limit is set only when the queue is first created.  Your program never removes the queue, so if you have been using the same queue name all the time then you may have a queue with a smaller size limit than you think.  Since you want this queue only for use within a single process, you should mq_unlink() it immediately after opening it.  That will prevent it outliving the process, and also be friendly to multiple different processes running your program concurrently.

Thanks for fast fast reply, while reducing the Code i removed These lines of Code. I had a cleanup function, that was closing and unlinking the queue (as Well as freeing all the allocated memory), also when an error occured During the program. But i tried with deleting the queue manually and still got that error.

You are setting attr.mq_maxmsg = 100 but only sending 70 bytes

Yes, @stark, and what?  attr.mq_maxmsg is a maximum size.

@Basti, I said you should unlink immediately after opening for your use case.  That will prevent the same queue being opened again, but it will not invalidate the queue that is already open from being used.  But if you're satisfied that you are not using an old queue, then this probably does not explain the failures you observe.

Problem is giving only 70 to the receiver.

@stark mq_maxmsg is the maximum number of messages allowed in queue. If you are talking about mq_msgsize, that's the maximum size and not the exact size, even if mq_msgsize was set to 100 and receiving only 70, this is not a problem.

@stark referring to the man (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) the mq_maxmsq defines the maximum numbers of messages, whereas where mq_msgsize definnes the maximum size of a single mesage.

i found a working solution, but i am still not sure what was the main problem.
in my solution now i have 2 structs:

message_content_t --> containing the path and name
message_t --> containing a char pointer

When i have created the message_content on the heap i store the address pointing to the heap in the char pointer. And when reading a message from the queue, i cast the msg_ptr from the message_t struct to message_content_t.
Here is my Code:
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define QUEUE_NAME "/test-123"
#define MAX_MESSAGES 10
#define MAX_MSG_SIZE 100

typedef struct message_content {
    char path[MAX_MSG_SIZE-20];
    char name[20];
} message_content_t;

typedef struct message{
    char *msg_ptr;
} message_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Message Queue File Descriptor for Sending
    mqd_t msgq_fd ;

    // Attributes of the Message queue
    struct mq_attr attr;
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = MAX_MESSAGES;
    attr.mq_msgsize = sizeof(message_t);
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

    // (Create and) open the message Queue for Writing only
    msgq_fd = mq_open(QUEUE_NAME, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0660, &attr);
    if(msgq_fd == (mqd_t)-1) {
        perror("Sender: mq_open failed");
        exit(4);
    }

    //Put 5 Messages into the Message queue
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        message_content_t *msg_content = calloc(1,sizeof(message_content_t));
        strcpy(msg_content->name,"test");
        strcpy(msg_content->path,"testpath");

        message_t msg;
        msg.msg_ptr = (char *)msg_content;

        printf("Message %d prepared...", i);

        // Error Sending 
        if(mq_send(msgq_fd, (const char *)&msg, sizeof(message_t), 0) == -1) {
                perror("Sender: unable to send message");
                mq_close(msgq_fd);
                exit(10);
        }
        printf("queued\n");
        sleep(1);

    }
    mq_close(msgq_fd);

    printf("\nReading messages from Queue\n");
    // Reopen the message queue for reading
    msgq_fd = mq_open(QUEUE_NAME, O_RDONLY);
    if (msgq_fd == (mqd_t)-1) {
        perror("mq_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t ret = 0;

    // Struct for storing the message from the Message Queue
    message_t recv_msg;

    // Read 5 messages from the Message Queue
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("(bytes_read: %ld) Message %d:\n",ret,i+1);
        sleep(1);

        ret = mq_receive(msgq_fd,(char*)&recv_msg,sizeof(message_t),NULL);

        // Error receiving
        if(ret == -1) {
            //printf("%d, %p, %ld\n",msgq_fd2, &recv_msg, sizeof(message_t));
            perror("Message receive error");
        }

        // Print the content of the received message
        message_content_t *ptr = (message_content_t *)recv_msg.msg_ptr;
        printf("%s/%s\n\n",ptr->path,ptr->name);
    }
    return 0;
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
